# Get the sum of a particular column using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to get the sum of the 5th column of a .csv file using bash, however the command I am using keeps getting me zero. I am piping the file through a grep to remove the column header row:

```
grep -v Header results.csv | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Is the data separated by spaces or commas?  If commas, you need to tell `awk` to split on them: `awk -F, …`.  Also, `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern: you need: `awk -F, '/Header/ { next } { sum += $5 } END { print sum }' results.csv` (no `grep`).  You could use `NR == 1` instead of `/Header/` to delete the first line of the data file.

Comment: Please post a sample of the csv file.

Comment: The data is separated by commas. Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: Show sample input data

Comment: When you are using `awk` you really don't need `grep` since `awk` is capable of doing what `grep` is typically used for. Given your question, I can  imagine `awk -F, 'NR>1 {sum += $5} END {print sum}' result.csv` should suffice. Having sample data will definitely help.

Answer (score 3):

here's how I would do it:

```
tail -n+2 | cut -d, -f5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

or:

```
tail -n+2 | awk -F, '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

(depending on what turns out to be faster.)